# Zoom and center selected portion of screen on MacOS

Tags: macos, zoom

The presenter in the video at https://developer.apple.com/wwdc18/407 does something fabulous with zoom on MacOS that I cannot figure out. He selects a portion of the screen (similar to the way you can select a portion of the screen to take a screenshot) and then zooms and centers on that selected area.

He does this several times. The first time is at about 13:35, though the selecting action can be difficult to see. It is much clearer when he does this at 17:22.

I've spent a good deal of time on Google to no avail. I can find no third-party software that adds this functionality to the system, either.

Is this a Mojave thing?

Answer (score 1):

This is not exclusively a feature of macOS Mojave. This is an old, built-in feature from OS X.

Navigate to:

- *System Preferences* → *Accessibility* → *Zoom*

Set *Zoom Style* to  <kbd>Picture-in-picture</kbd> .

You can adjust the coordinates of the selected portion by clicking  <kbd>More Options...</kbd>  →  <kbd>Adjust Size And Location</kbd> .

Comment: @rubiks-sphere, I found and enabled that P-in-P functionality when researching this. (Sorry, should have included that fact in the original post.) It does not behave the way shown in that video (or at least, I can't get it to). Specifically, it does not seem to allow any sort of selection, _a la_ screenshot. I hope it goes without saying that I would **love** to be wrong here. Am I?

Comment: I understand what you are describing. Sorry, I do not know how he set the box coordinates in real-time like that.